# How do I calculate a specific variation for a known value of the normal distribution function?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I am writing a Gaussian blur filter in graphics shader code.  I want to make the blur parameterized by radius from the users perspective.  The best method I can figure to do this is to pick a suitable stopping point for y, say .001, and solve for the variance to plug into the normal distribution function that will achieve that value of y.

Unfortunately I cannot for the life of me solve this equation for v...

$x = 10$ (blur radius)

$$.001 = \frac{1}{2 \pi v^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2v^2}}$$.

Comment: I have tried to convert to latex (which you can do by enclosing in `$` signs), so if things aren't what you expect, let me know.

Comment: It looks like there is a typo here.  If this is supposed to be the probability density function for an isotropic binormal distribution in 2d and $x$ is the radial coordinate, then it needs to be multiplied by $x$.  (This won't change the solution *methods* already proposed, but it affects the details.)  A few Newton-Raphson iterations should suffice to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the suggestion to use the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), I'll show how it arises in your equation of interest.

Starting with

$y=\frac1{2\pi v^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2v^2}\right)$

we multiply both sides by $-\pi x^2$ to give

$-\pi x^2 y=-\frac{x^2}{2v^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2v^2}\right)$

which can now be inverted to the Lambert function (recall that the Lambert function $W(z)$ is the inverse function of $z\exp(z)$, $W(z)\exp(W(z))=z$):

$-\frac{x^2}{2v^2}=W(-\pi x^2 y)$

which we can now solve for $v$

$v=\frac{x}{\sqrt{-2W(-\pi x^2 y)}}$

The choice of sign for the square root is motivated by the fact that variances are conventionally taken to be positive.

Comment: +1. I suggest you add a brief explanation of the Lambert function. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Moron: Done, hopefully the one line explanation of the Lambert function is crystal-clear.

Comment: Heh, should've done that to begin with. Thank you Kaestur!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the radius has to involve the variance. You could just use the radius to scale the x-axis.

So you could sample the distribution from -1 to 1, always. If the radius is 4, would sample 9 regions. For 10 you sample 21 times between -1 and 1. The variance can stay the same.

You might want to try this question here too https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.